# Reading various parts of binary file in c

Tags: c, file-io

I am writing a program to read specific parts of a binary file and I am having trouble getting it to read the right lengths of the binary at the right locations in the file. I've been trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong for some time now but with no success.

Here is what my code looks like

```
int project(char * rel, char * atr){  takes in the name of the relation to look in and the name of the attribute to look for

    char tmpstr[MAX_LEN+5], tmpstr2[MAX_LEN+5], attr[MAX_LEN+5], type[MAX_LEN+5], names[MAX_LEN+5];//attr is the attribute read by pass of fscanf()
    int numbytes = 0, numtups = 0, nummove = 0, skip = 0, i = 0;    //the length in bytes of the atr, number of tuples to read
    FILE* f1;
    FILE* f2;
    strcpy(tmpstr, rel);
    strncat(tmpstr,".sch", 4); // appends '.sch' extension to the file name
    if((f1 =(FILE*)fopen(tmpstr, "r")) == NULL){  // opens "InsertFileNameHere.sch"
        return -1;
    }
    if(fscanf(f1, "%d", &numattr) != 1){
        return -1;
    }
    strcpy(tmpstr2, rel);
    strncat(tmpstr2,".dat", 4); // appends '.dat' extension to the file name
    if((f2 =(FILE*)fopen(tmpstr2, "rb")) == NULL){  // opens "InsertFileNameHere.dat"
        return -1;
    }

    fscanf(f1, "%s", attr);  
    fscanf(f1, "%1s", type);
    fscanf(f1, "%d", &numbytes);
    while((strcmp(attr, atr) != 0) || numattr == 0){ //While the attr is = to the atr or you have run out of attributes to scan, keep scanning
        skip = skip + numbytes*2;
        fscanf(f1, "%s", attr);
        fscanf(f1, "%1s", type);
        fscanf(f1, "%d", &numbytes);
        numattr--;
        if(numattr == 0){
            return -2;
        }
        fseek(f2, skip, SEEK_CUR);
    }
    nummove = tuplen(rel) - numbytes*2;
    numtups = count(rel);
    printf("%d\n", nummove);
    while(i < numtups){
        fread(names, 1, numbytes*2, f2);
        fprintf(stdout, "%s\n", names);
        fseek(f2, skip, SEEK_CUR);
        i++;
    }
    puts("\n");
    fclose(f1);
    fclose(f2);
    return 1;

}
```

The files I have been using to test this code are as follows:

Students.sch: The first line of this file is the amount of subsequent lines in the file. On each line is a string followed by the type of data to be read from the binary file, then the number of bytes to read from the binary file.
This file is used to tell the program how to read the binary file.

```
5
Name   S  25
Major  S  4
Minor  S  4
Totcr  I  4
Majcr  I  4
```

Students.dat: This file contains all the information to be read

```
536d 6974 682c 526f 6265 7274 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0050 5359 0043 5349
0000 0000 3900 0000 2757 6f6f 6473 2c4a
616e 6500 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 4353 4900 4255 5300 0000 0061 0000
0044 5261 6d73 6579 2c45 6c61 696e 6500
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0042 5553 0050
5359 0000 0000 6b00 0000 5857 6861 7274
6f6e 2c54 6f6d 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 4255 5300 5053 5900 0000 0075
0000 0062 4261 6b65 722c 4e6f 726d 6100
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0042 494f
0043 5349 0000 0000 2700 0000 19
```

Any help is appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: **WHAT** is this cast `(FILE *)` for? what is the return type of `fopen()`? did you include `stdio.h`?????

Comment: I was getting a warning when I didn't have that cast. The files both open successfully from those calls. Yes I did include stdio.h they just got cut off because my question has more to do with the while loops that I am running that read from the files.

Comment: Why was you getting a warning, you should check that instead of silencing the warning with the cast, that warning means something is wrong because I am very very sure that you don't need that cast at all.

Comment: I took the casts out, and now the warnings that i put them there for are gone... I'm not sure why this is but you are right about not needing the casts

Comment: I thought it would read the same thing each iteration if i used SEEK_SET ??

Comment: after adding the stdio.h, stdlib.h and string.h headers I ran the code through the gcc compiler, with all warnings enabled.  The results is 16 items, some of which are 'errors'  so the code would never have compiled.  the first problem is the comment immediately after the open brace.  That comment is missing the leading '//'  Things go downhill from there.  Please compile the code with all warnings enabled, fix the warnings, and re-post the corrected code.  For best results, include everything needed for a clean compile

Comment: the code block beginning with: 'if(numattr == 0){' exits the function with out cleaning up.  I.E. it does not close open files,

Comment: the returned value from fscanf() and family, should always be checked to assure the operation was successful.  The posted code on checks the returned value occasionally.  the returned value from fseek() should be checked to assure the operation was successful.  the returned value from fread() should be checked to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: the code block beginning with: 'while((strcmp(attr, atr) != 0) || numattr == 0)'  if numattr is 0, then the line: 'numattr--'' would make it -1  This is probably not what is wanted, especially given the check 'if(numattr == 0)' cause an exit from the function.

Comment: the line 'fseek(f2, skip, SEEK_CUR);  causes larger and large jumps forward through the file, with each jump starting at the current location in the file.   While the details of the file have not been revealed, I suspect this is not what the code should be doing.

Comment: please post the updated code, so we are all looking at the same thing.

Comment: regarding using SEEK_CUR or using SEEK_SET:  the variable 'skip' is being incremented in each itteration through the while loop.  if the increment is the distance between the end of the current data and the beginning of the next data, and that distance is dramatically increasing then the code might be ok,  However, if the distance is staying the same, then the SEEK_CUR and keeping skip the same would be acceptable  Or keep increasing 'skip' and start from the beginning of the file using SEEK_SET.  suggest reading the man page for fseek() to get the details of how to use it.

Comment: you said that 'any help is appreciated'  but I'm not seeing the expected results of our help reflected in the posted code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a problem here

```
fscanf(f1, "%s", attr);
fscanf(f1, "%1s", type);
fscanf(f1, "%d", &numbytes);
```

you must be sure that you read the correct values, so you need to check the return value of `fscanf()`, and also it all can fit in a single format string like this

```
if (fscanf(f1, "%s%1s%d", attr, type, &numbyts) != 3)
    /* ... there is a problem with the data, do not continue ... */
```

also, give length modifiers to every `"%s"` specifier to prevent buffer overflow.

Comment: I am not reading the binary file with fscanf(). I am reading the "Students.sch" file with those calls. In the second while loop is where I am reading the binary file

Comment: Maybe I should have been more clear in the question. But the Students.sch and Students.dat do not contain the some information in just different file types. Students.dat translates to a few records of information about made up students.

Comment: irregardless of which file is being read, the returned value from fscanf() should always be checked to assure the input/conversion operation(s) were successful

Comment: "%1s", following the prior "%s" will fail because the file pointer will be pointing to a whitespace character and the %s input conversion format will not skip over white space.  suggest placing a ' ' whitespace between each of the format specifiers,  as a ' ' will cause the skipping of any/all whitespace

Comment: @user3629249 the only specifier that requires a explicit `' '` is `"%c"`.